# Rails restful select in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I enter the following URL in a browser, I get a list of client records:

```
http://localhost:5000/clients.json
```

Now, I would like to be able the select certain clients via the URL.  Is something like this possible:

```
http://localhost:5000/clients.json?locname=ys
```

This is my clients_controller.rb for index:

```
def index
  @clients = Client.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @clients }
  end
end
```

THANKS!

Comment: Can we see your clients_controller.rb file please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
def index
  @clients = Client.scoped
  @clients = @clients.where(:locname => params[:locname]) if params[:locname].present?

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @clients }
  end
end
```

Comment: I get 'undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x007f90352a4500>'

Comment: I tried find instead of where - but, then the format.json line gives me = undefined method `call' for {:locname=>"ys"}:Hash

Comment: This worked = @clients = Client.where(:locname => params[:locname]) if params[:locname].present?

Comment: Follow-up question.  How would I code finding a created_at date past a certain date.  I tried this:      @expenses = Client.where(:created_at > params[:after]) if params[:after].present?

Comment: I also tried =     @expenses = Client.where(:created_at => params[:after]) if params[:after].present? and URL = http://localhost:5000/expenses.json?after>2013-04-13

Comment: Try this:

`@expenses = Client.where("created_at = #{params[:after]} OR created_at > #{params[:after]}") if params[:after].present?`

Comment: Andrei - sorry, I switched to a different table/controller.  I'm trying to pull expenses created past a certain date.

Comment: Andrei - If I just put in a date, like this:  http://localhost:5000/expenses.json?after=2013-04-12, then I get this PG error = PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone = numeric

Comment: I tried this - but, it didn't work = @expenses = Client.where("created_at > #{params[:after].to_datetime}") if params[:after].present?

Comment: Somehow I need to get the where clause to add quotes around the date = SELECT * FROM "expenses"  WHERE (created_at > '2013-04-12')

Comment: Got it - I just had to put that in the URL !!! http://localhost:5000/expenses.json?after='2013-04-13'